# Loading select options via AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Currently I have a select option where I'm running a forloop to fetch all the records from the database like so:

```
<?php if($cities) foreach($cities as $cit): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $cit['id']; ?>" <?php echo ($listing[0]['emirate'] == $cit['id'])?'selected="selected"':''?>><?php echo $cit['name']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now this fetches around 30000 entries from my database which slows down my page everytime it is loaded in because it adds an extra 30000 lines of code. So I want a way to call this through a AJAX request that loads another view with the same forloop. To do this I tried creating a new file named ajaxcities.php and placed the following code:

```
<select name="emirate" class="form-control select2 selectsearch" <?php echo (isset($read) ? $read:''); ?> required>
    <option value="<?php echo set_value('country'); ?>">Select City</option>
    <?php if($cities) foreach($cities as $cit): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cit['id']; ?>" <?php echo ($listing[0]['emirate'] == $cit['id'])?'selected="selected"':''?>><?php echo $cit['name']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Then I replaced this code where it was previously in my view class before to this:

```
<label class="control-labels ">City</label>
<span id="city-wrap">
<div class="invalid-feedback">Please choose a City</div>
<script>
function getcity(obj){
  var dataString = new Object();
  dataString.type = obj.val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('listings/ajaxgetcity'); ?>/",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(result) { 
      $('#city-wrap').html(result);  
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

And made a new controller with the following:

```
public function ajaxgetcity()
{
    $views['cities'] = $this->listings_model->cities();
    $this->load->view('crm/listings/ajaxcities',$views,false);
}
```

But this removed the select dropbox altogether. I want a way to load this only with an AJAX call and not everytime the page is reloaded

Comment: Did you wrap your javascript code in `<script>` tags?

Comment: Yes I have @RiggsFolly

Comment: I strongly suggest you make a select that can somehow chop the results.
For example if names, have the user type for example 3 letters of the entry and load a max of 1000 entries

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: What is the use case of showing 30000 cities in one drop down? That is not a good idea. Make a datalist and populate it when the user has typed something